# How to make words separate without space in android studio

Tags: string, android-studio, kotlin

I have different numbers and calculation signs in a string format text in android studio. I want my numbers show correctly but if I do not put space before signs my numbers are shown separately when text get to end of lines. If I put space, so I will have redundant spaces in my screen. What should I do to have correct shown numbers and not to have redundant spaces?! My program is in Kotlin language.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read up on how to ask a good question here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then provide some information on what you have tried already and what your code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the triple quote(""") option in Kotlin. It's good for specifying exactly how you want the text to look. This code:

```
val string = """
Multiple
line string
"""
println(string)
```

Will show:

```
Multiple 
line string
```

Comment: It is good, but it is not my answer. I mean what should I do to separate words without putting space. For example when I have 123+365+4785+9812 in a string, if it is greater than screen width I will see for example                              123+365+4785+98                                                                                                        12 (12 in next line of screen)  meanwhile 9812 is one number and should be seen together in screen.